# How to use hasUniqueness check in PyDeequ?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-quality, amazon-deequ

I'm using [PyDeequ](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ) for data quality and I want to check the uniqueness of a set of columns. There is a Check method `hasUniqueness` but I can't figure how to use it.

I'm trying:

```
check.hasUniqueness([col1, col2], ????)
```

But what should we use here for the assertion function in place of `????`?

Has anyone tried the check `hasUniqueness` for a combination of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`hasUniqueness`](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/blob/e358c835172a3a74c33a246550c2783be5df6123/pydeequ/checks.py#L242) takes a function that accepts an in/float parameter and returns a boolean :

> Creates a constraint that asserts any uniqueness in a single or
> combined set of key columns. Uniqueness is the fraction of unique
> values of a column(s)  values that occur exactly once.

Here's an example of usage :

```
df.show()
#+---+---+
#|  a|  b|
#+---+---+
#|foo|  1|
#|bar|  0|
#|baz|  1|
#|bar|  0|
#+---+---+
```

In this dataframe, the combination of columns `a` and `b` has 2 values that occur exactly once `(foo, 1)` and `(baz, 1)` so `Uniqueness = 0.5` here. Let's verify it using the check constraint :

```
from pydeequ.checks import CheckLevel, Check
from pydeequ.verification import VerificationResult, VerificationSuite

result = VerificationSuite(spark).onData(df).addCheck(
    Check(spark, CheckLevel.Warning, "test hasUniqueness")
        .hasUniqueness(["a", "b"], lambda x: x == 0.5)
).run()

result_df = VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, result)

result_df.select("constraint_status").show()

#+-----------------+
#|constraint_status|
#+-----------------+
#|          Success|
#+-----------------+
```